# Determining the correct order in which jars should be compiled?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, graph

we are given a set of jars, with dependencies over each other. How can we determine the correct ordering in which jars should be compiled?

A->B and C

B-> D and E

D->E and C

E->F

F->C

Comment: Since you added the tag graph, have you actually tried to create a dependency graph? It should be pretty obvious then, how the dependencies are and what you have to compile first.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Answer (score 1):

A nice graph will tell you right away:

[image]

What would you say after seeing this?

PS - [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Download..php) is a great tool.

Comment: Cycles in the graph make this problem even more fun.

Comment: I see no cycles. The graph makes it easy to see: work from bottom to top.

Comment: Sorry. I just mean that if there are cycles in the dependency graph. There are none in the example given.

Comment: Cycles in the graph mean "these two JARs are really one", because you can't build or test without both of them.